# Are open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ countable unions of disjoint open rectangles?

Tags: measure-theory

I'm just trying to prove that each open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is measurable using the product measure derived from the Lebesgue measure.  This is the first thing that came to mind because I recall that open sets are countable unions of disjoint open intervals, but I was wondering if there is an elementary way to do this.

Comment: Use sets of the form $[a,b) \times [c,d)$ instead.

Answer (score 6):

The answer to the question is *no*: the set of points lying below the line $y=-x$, for instance, is not a union of countable many pairwise disjoint open rectangles.

Comment: Would open spheres fail as well?

Comment: @user54358: I’m afraid so. With them you cannot, for instance, fill the unit square exactly.

Comment: Wait, do i need these rectangles to be disjoint to conclude that the countable union is measurable?

Comment: The answer is yes,let $U$ be a open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$,we can write $U=A\times B$ s,t $A,B$ are open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $A,B$ are countable unions disjoint open interval,then $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$,$B=\bigcup_{j\in J}B_j$ s,t $A_i,B_j$ are open interval for $i\in I,j\in J$ and $I,J$ are countable sets,we know $A_i\times B_j$ is open rectangle($(a,b)\times (c,d)$ is open rectangle)and $I\times J$ is countable,hence we have $U=\bigcup_{i\in I,j\ J}(A_i\times B_j)$,($A_i\times B_j$s are disjoint because $A_i$s and $B_j$s are disjoint).

Comment: @user54358 no. To show that a countable union is measurable it's enough to show that each set involved is measurable.

Comment: No,I answer to "are open setS in $\mathbb{R}^2$ countable unions of disjoint open rectangles"?