# Open sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as countable union of disjoint open rectangles

Tags: real-analysis

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354535/are-open-sets-in-mathbbr2-countable-unions-of-disjoint-open-rectangles) I realize that there exists an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is *not* a disjoint union of open rectangles. The example given is the set of points lying below the line $y=-x$.

However, I can't quite see how one would prove that that particular set is not a disjoint union of open rectangles. What contradiction can one derive if that set were to be a disjoint union of open rectangles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one thing, a *disjoint* union of a family of open sets can only be connected if at most one member of the family is non-empty. The half-plane $\{y < -x\}$ is connected and not an open rectangle, hence it cannot be the disjoint union of open rectangles.

Another way to see it is to note that in a disjoint union of open rectangles, no boundary point of any rectangle can be covered. For any open set containing the boundary point must intersect the rectangle of which it is a boundary point.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C$ be the set in question. It should be clear that $C$ is connected.

If $C=\cup_n R_n$, where $R_n$ are open pairwise disjoint non-empty rectangles, then $C = R_1 \cup (\cup_{n \neq 1} R_n)$, that is, $C$ is disconnected, a contradiction.